# Matching ids against each other with error if invalid, if correct display data if not display error. Displays Error for both correct and incorrect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Table Of Contents:

1. Quick Run Trough of what the code does.
2. CODE
3. Successes.
4. Errors
5. What I expected and what is actually being outputted
6. What I have tried to solve these errors

## 1. Quick Run Trough of what the code does.

Its a simple clock in and out system, using an RFID Reader.
The user has one field which is filed using the reader itself after the employee swipes.
I use an ajax script to handle the posting, once the form is submitted the PHP handles the rest.

i have created a simple system. check the current date with the form date if it matches and if the employee has not clocked in yet for the day. Insert the timestamp and reload the page for the next employee.

## 2. CODE

**HTML And JS**

```js
       $("body").on("submit", "#clockInOut", function(e){
            var rfidNumber = $('#rfidNumber').val();
            swal.showLoading();
            if (rfidNumber == "") {
                swal.fire({
                    icon: "error",
                    title: "No Input",
                    html: "<b>Enter Your Employee ID, cannot be blank!</b>",
                    timer: 1500,
                    showConfirmButton: false
                });
            } else {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?= $site->baseURL; ?>/",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        rfidNumber: rfidNumber
                    },
                    success: function ( result ) {
                        $('#rfidNumber').val('');
                        console.log(result);
                        if (result.success) {
                            swal.fire({
                                icon: "success",
                                title: result.title ,
                                html: result.html,
                                showConfirmButton: false,
                                timer: 2000 
                            });
                        } else if (result.error) {
                        swal.fire({
                            icon: "error",
                            title: result.title,
                            html: result.html,
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            timer: 5000
                        });
                        }
                    },
                    error: function ( result ) {
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });
            }
       });
```

```html
    <div class="login-box" style="height: 100%; margin-top: 5%;">
        <div class="login-logo">
            <a>
                <?= "<img src='" . $site->info['logo'] . "' style='height: 100px; width: 100px;'><br /><b>" . $site->info['title'] . "</b>" ?></a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.login-logo -->
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body login-card-body">
                <p class="login-box-msg">
                    <div class="login-logo">
                        <p id="date"></p>
                        <p id="time" class="bold"></p>
                    </div>
                </p>
                <form id="clockInOut" method="post">

                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" minlength="7" maxlength="8" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^1-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" id="rfidNumber" placeholder="RFID Number" required autofocus>
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-4">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col -->
                    </div>
                </form>
                <hr>
                <p class="mb-1">
                    <a href="forgot-password.html">I forgot my Employee ID</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.login-card-body -->
        </div>
        <center>
        </center>
    </div>
```

**PHP Handler**

```html
if(isset($_POST['rfidNumber'])){

    $rfidNumber = $_POST['rfidNumber'];

  $getRfidNumbers = $functions->runSQL("SELECT `id`, `employee_id`, `rfid_card_number` FROM `employeeids` WHERE `available` = '0'");
  $getRfidNumbers->execute();

  $rfidNumbers = $getRfidNumbers->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $rfidArr = [];
  foreach ($rfidNumbers as $key => $value) {
    $rfidArr = array($value['rfid_card_number']);
  }
  // Check If Employee ID exists
  if (!in_array($rfidNumber, $rfidArr)) {
      $error = array(
        "error" => "error",
        "title" => "<b style='color:red;'>Invalid RFID Number</b>",
        "html" => "<b>Forgot Your RFID Number ?<br />Use the Forgot link to get your RFID Number.</b>"
      );
      print json_encode($error); 
  }

  $currentTime = date("H:i:s");
  $date = date('Y-m-d');

  foreach ($rfidNumbers as $key => $value) {
     if ($rfidNumber == $value['rfid_card_number']) {
      $getAttendance = $functions->runSQL("SELECT `id`, `employee_id`, `rfid_card_number`, `date`, `clock_in`, `status`, `clock_out`, `num_hours` FROM `attendance` WHERE `rfid_card_number` = :rfidNumber");
      $getAttendance->execute(array(
        ":rfidNumber" => $value['id']
      ));
      $attendance = $getAttendance->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      $getEmployeeDetails = $functions->runSQL("SELECT `firstname`, `lastname` FROM `employees` WHERE `rfid_card_number` = :rfidNumber");
      $getEmployeeDetails->execute(array(
        ":rfidNumber" => $value['id']
      ));
      $employeeDetails = $getEmployeeDetails->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $employeeName = $employeeDetails['firstname'] . " " . $employeeDetails['lastname'];

      if ($attendance == NULL) {
        // Not Clocked In
        $workingHoursStart = explode(':', $dashboard->workingHours['open']);
        $clockInGrace = $workingHoursStart[1] + $dashboard->attendanceGrace['in'];
        $ontime = $workingHoursStart[0] . $clockInGrace . $workingHoursStart[2];
        if (date("Y-m-d H:i:s") > date("Y-m-d " . $ontime)) {
          // Employee Late
          $insertClockInLate = $functions->runSQL("INSERT INTO `attendance`(`employee_id`, `rfid_card_number`, `date`, `clock_in`, `status`, `clock_out`, `num_hours`) VALUES (:employeeID, :rfidNumber, :dates, :clockIn, 'late', NULL, '0')");
          $insertClockInLate->bindparam(":employeeID", $value['employee_id']);
          $insertClockInLate->bindparam(":rfidNumber", $value['id']);
          $insertClockInLate->bindparam(":dates", $date);
          $insertClockInLate->bindparam(":clockIn", $currentTime);
          if ($insertClockInLate->execute()) {
            $clockedIn = array(
              "success" => "success",
              "title" => "<b>" . $employeeName . "<b style='color:red;'>(LATE)</b></b>",
              "html" => "<center style='font-size:22px;><b style='color:green;'>Clocked In</b><b style='color:red;'> Your&apos;e late.</b></center>'"
            );
            print json_encode($clockedIn);
          }
        } elseif (date('Y-m-d H:i:s') < date("Y-m-d " . $workingHoursStart[1])) {
          // Employee Early
          $insertClockInEarly = $functions->runSQL("INSERT INTO `attendance`(`employee_id`, `rfid_card_number`, `date`, `clock_in`, `status`, `clock_out`, `num_hours`) VALUES (:employeeID, :rfidNumber, :dates, :clockIn, 'early', NULL, '0')");
          $insertClockInEarly->bindparam(":employeeID", $value['employee_id']);
          $insertClockInEarly->bindparam(":rfidNumber", $value['id']);
          $insertClockInEarly->bindparam(":dates", $date);
          $insertClockInEarly->bindparam(":clockIn", $currentTime);
          if ($insertClockInEarly->execute()) {
            $clockedIn = array(
              "success" => "success",
              "title" => "<b>" . $employeeName . "<b style='color:green;'>(Early)</b></b>",
              "html" => "<center style='font-size:22px;><b style='color:green;'>Clocked In</b><b style='color:green;'> Your&apos;e Early.</b></center>"
            );
            print json_encode($clockedIn);
          }
        } elseif (date("Y-m-d H:i:s") < date("Y-m-d " . $ontime)) {
          // Employee On Time
          $insertClockInOnTime = $functions->runSQL("INSERT INTO `attendance`(`employee_id`, `rfid_card_number`, `date`, `clock_in`, `status`, `clock_out`, `num_hours`) VALUES (:employeeID, :rfidNumber, :dates, :clockIn, 'on-time', NULL, '0')");
          $insertClockInOnTime->bindparam(":employeeID", $value['employee_id']);
          $insertClockInOnTime->bindparam(":rfidNumber", $value['id']);
          $insertClockInOnTime->bindparam(":dates", $date);
          $insertClockInOnTime->bindparam(":clockIn", $currentTime);
          if ($insertClockInOnTime->execute()) {
            $clockedIn = array(
              "success" => "success",
              "title" => "<b>" . $employeeName . "<b style='color:green;'>(ON-TIME)</b></b>",
              "html" => "<center style='font-size:22px;><b style='color:green;'>Clocked In</b><b style='color:green;'> Your&apos;e On-Time.</b></center>'"
            );
            print json_encode($clockedIn);
          }
        }
      } else {
        // Employee Clock Out
        foreach ($attendance as $key => $ta_attendance) {
          if ( $ta_attendance['date'] == $date ) {
            print json_encode($ta_attendance);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## 3. Successes

I was able to match the employee ids against each other and if valid input the user attendance into the db while checking if early,on-time,late. if invalid display error.

## 4. Errors

DB Attendance is 0. if i use and clock in one user its a success

html: "<center style='font-size:22px;>Clocked In Your'e late.'"
success: "success"
title: "**Lola1 Sec1(LATE)**"

the second clock in, even though user is valid:

responseText: "{"error":"error","title":"Invalid RFID Number<\/b>","html":"**Forgot Your RFID Number ?<br \/>Use the Forgot link to get your RFID Number.<\/b>"}{"success":"success","title":"**Lola Sec(LATE)<\/b><\/b>","html":"<center style='font-size:22px;>Clocked In<\/b> Your'e late.<\/b><\/center>'"}"****

if the user enters an invalid id the correct error displays

error: "error"
html: "Forgot Your RFID Number ?
Use the Forgot link to get your RFID Number."
title: "Invalid RFID Number"

if the user is clocked in (first one without errors) tries to clock out, the response is:

responseText: "{"error":"error","title":"Invalid RFID Number<\/b>","html":"Forgot Your RFID Number ?<br \/>Use the Forgot link to get your RFID Number.<\/b>"}{"id":"130","employee_id":"FSJ0001","rfid_card_number":"1","date":"2020-12-31","clock_in":"21:10:48","status":"late","clock_out":null,"num_hours":"0"}"

invalid error still displays.

Now when a user tries to clock in with a valid id again.the invalid key displays

responseText: "{"error":"error","title":"Invalid RFID Number<\/b>","html":"Forgot Your RFID Number ?<br \/>Use the Forgot link to get your RFID Number.<\/b>"}{"id":"130","employee_id":"FSJ0001","rfid_card_number":"1","date":"2020-12-31","clock_in":"21:10:48","status":"late","clock_out":null,"num_hours":"0"}"

**5. What i have tried to solve these errors**

```html
  if (!in_array($rfidNumber, $rfidArr)) {
      $error = array(
        "error" => "error",
        "title" => "<b style='color:red;'>Invalid RFID Number</b>",
        "html" => "<b>Forgot Your RFID Number ?<br />Use the Forgot link to get your RFID Number.</b>"
      );
      print json_encode($error); 
  }
```

I have moved the above script at the beginning of the if statements, does the same thing.

if i remove it and add a `elseif ($value['rfid_card_number'] !== $rfidNumber)` still does the same thing with a few different errors.

**NOTE: EmployeeIds table store the actual rfid number, the rest of the dbs store the id **

I have been at it for 2 days, cant seem to find my way around handling this error or if there is a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It's time to refactor!

When you can't see the forest for all the trees, it's time to refactor.  As I was looking over your code, I keep getting lost in all the stuff in the second `foreach ($rfidNumbers as $key => $value)` loop.  The irony is, it's not even getting there on the second user.

#### Debugging Step for Initial Problem:

All of the errors come down to one thing:  You're not finding a matching record in `employeeids`.  Which brings up a question:  why download the entire table and then search through the entire array, when you could just do that in the database query?

```
"SELECT id, employee_id, rfid_card_number FROM employeeids WHERE available = '0' and rfid_card_number=:rfidNumber"
```

Run that query in phpmyadmin, and examine the (lack of) results.  Then run a `select * from employeeids` and see why the query is failing.  You didn't show any code that affects the field, `available`, but I suspect it may have a null value which will cause the query to ignore that row. Or, perhaps you're changing the state of `available` to a non-zero value.

*hint:* It may not even be failing on the record you think it's failing on.  For debugging, you could add the rfid number/employee id in the error. You also should probably `exit` the script after any `print json_encode($error);`.

#### Further Issues

```
  foreach ($rfidNumbers as $key => $value) {
     if ($rfidNumber == $value['rfid_card_number']) {
```

The loop is unnecessary if you grab just the record you need from employeeids.

---

```
$getAttendance = $functions->runSQL("SELECT `id`, `employee_id`, `rfid_card_number`, `date`, `clock_in`, `status`, `clock_out`, `num_hours` FROM `attendance` WHERE `rfid_card_number` = :rfidNumber");
```

This query is going to gather all records of logins, not the current one.  You probably want to `order by id desc limit 1`.

---

```
if ($attendance == NULL) {
```

Need to check the fields, not the row.  This will only be taken the first time you run the script.

---

You should refactor all the duplicated code here:

```
        if (date("Y-m-d H:i:s") > date("Y-m-d " . $ontime)) {
          // Employee Late
          $insertClockInLate = $functions->runSQL("INSERT INTO `attendance`(`employee_id`, `rfid_card_number`, `date`, `clock_in`, `status`, `clock_out`, `num_hours`) VALUES (:employeeID, :rfidNumber, :dates, :clockIn, 'late', NULL, '0')");
          $insertClockInLate->bindparam(":employeeID", $value['employee_id']);
          $insertClockInLate->bindparam(":rfidNumber", $value['id']);
          $insertClockInLate->bindparam(":dates", $date);
          $insertClockInLate->bindparam(":clockIn", $currentTime);
          if ($insertClockInLate->execute()) {
            $clockedIn = array(
              "success" => "success",
              "title" => "<b>" . $employeeName . "<b style='color:red;'>(LATE)</b></b>",
              "html" => "<center style='font-size:22px;><b style='color:green;'>Clocked In</b><b style='color:red;'> Your&apos;e late.</b></center>'"
            );
            print json_encode($clockedIn);
          }
        } elseif (date('Y-m-d H:i:s') < date("Y-m-d " . $workingHoursStart[1])) {
          // Employee Early
          $insertClockInEarly = $functions->runSQL("INSERT INTO `attendance`(`employee_id`, `rfid_card_number`, `date`, `clock_in`, `status`, `clock_out`, `num_hours`) VALUES (:employeeID, :rfidNumber, :dates, :clockIn, 'early', NULL, '0')");
          $insertClockInEarly->bindparam(":employeeID", $value['employee_id']);
          $insertClockInEarly->bindparam(":rfidNumber", $value['id']);
          $insertClockInEarly->bindparam(":dates", $date);
          $insertClockInEarly->bindparam(":clockIn", $currentTime);
          if ($insertClockInEarly->execute()) {
 ...etc
```

to something like

```
$workingHoursStart = explode(':', $dashboard->workingHours['open']);
$clockInGrace = $workingHoursStart[1] + $dashboard->attendanceGrace['in'];
$ontime = $workingHoursStart[0] . $clockInGrace . $workingHoursStart[2];
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$clock_out = null;
if($now > date('Y-m-d').' '.$ontime) {
    $status = 'late';
    $message = [
        "success" => "success",
        "title" => "<b>" . $employeeName . "<b style='color:red;'>(LATE)</b></b>",
        "html" => "<center style='font-size:22px;><b style='color:green;'>Clocked In</b><b style='color:red;'> Your&apos;e late.</b></center>'"
    ];
}
if($now < $date('Y-m-d') . ' ' . $workingHoursStart[1]) {
    $status = 'early';
    $message = [
        "success" => "success",
        "title" => "<b>" . $employeeName . "<b style='color:green;'>(Early)</b></b>",
        "html" => "<center style='font-size:22px;><b style='color:green;'>Clocked In</b><b style='color:green;'> Your&apos;e Early.</b></center>"
    ];
if (date("Y-m-d H:i:s") < date("Y-m-d " . $ontime)) {
    $status = 'on-time';
    $message = [
        "success" => "success",
        "title" => "<b>" . $employeeName . "<b style='color:green;'>(ON-TIME)</b></b>"
        "html" => "<center style='font-size:22px;><b style='color:green;'>Clocked In</b><b style='color:green;'> Your&apos;e On-Time.</b></center>'"
    ];
}

$insertClockInOnTime = $functions->runSQL("INSERT INTO `attendance`(`employee_id`, `rfid_card_number`, `date`, `clock_in`, `status`, `clock_out`, `num_hours`) VALUES (:employeeID, :rfidNumber, :dates, :clockIn, :status, NULL, '0')");
$insertClockInOnTime->bindparam(":employeeID", $value['employee_id']);
$insertClockInOnTime->bindparam(":rfidNumber", $value['id']);
$insertClockInOnTime->bindparam(":dates", $date);
$insertClockInOnTime->bindparam(":clockIn", $currentTime);
$insertClockInOnTime->bindparam(":status", $status);
```

I didn't refactor `$message`, but it could easily be refactored also, especially if you use css instead of inline style.

Comment: Thank you Tim, I did not think of refactoring the code as i was busy with it, although since you brought it the point to me. I was also getting a bit lost after the foreach > ifs.. Just got access to my repo. Will update that page with your refactored code.

Comment: 'available' is either set to 0 or 1. If the employeeID is used in the employeeids table it will make 'available' = 0 if not it will be '1' so that it would allow more employee profiles to be created.

Comment: i have to have the employeeIDs table as it holds both the employeeID and the RFID assigned to it. I simply store the row id in the employee profile table and if needed i can call the employeeID table